# Asp.net core localization culture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to change default culture "en" to "vi".

But it doesn't work.

- **View**

_Layout.cshtml

```
    <div>
        <a href="/?culture=vi" style="margin-right: 16px;">Tiếng Việt</a>
        <a href="/?culture=en">English</a>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:12px;">
        <h2>@SharedLocalizer["Welcome"]</h2>
    </div>
```

index.cshtml

```
    @inject IViewLocalizer Localizer;

    <div style="padding:32px;">
       <h1>Value: @Localizer["Value"]</h1>
    </div>
```

- **Startup.cs**

  ```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
          services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
          services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
      }
      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
      {
          List<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
          {
              new CultureInfo("vi"),
              new CultureInfo("en"),
          };

          app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
          {
              DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("vi"),
              SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
              SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
          });

          app.UseStaticFiles();

          app.UseMvc(routes =>
          {
              routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
          });
      }
  ```

  - **Sources**

SharedResources.en.resx

SharedResources.vi.resx

Views.Home.Index.en.resx

Views.Home.Index.vi.resx

Comment: What are your namespaces of `SharedResource`? Are they in the same assembly? Please read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization), there is a section about naming conventions __Resources are named for the full type name of their class minus the assembly name.__. Also if your assembly name differs from your **default namespace**, there are issues obtaining the correct resource name. See this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/398)

Comment: Thanks @Tseng for replying. the namespace is Localization_Basic.Resources. It runs fine. however I can't change "en" culture to "vi" culture. I must delete "en" resource, the culture change will change to "vi". For testing, I add another culture like "fr", it still run fine. The problem is always pick up "en" culture firstly.

Comment: You have to add `culture=fr` to your url (or set cookie or language header), i.e. `http://localhost/home/index?culture=vi`. `http://localhost/home/index?culture=vi-VN` won't work, unless you have set `FallBackToParentCultures = true` and/or `FallBackToParentUICultures = true` in your `RequestLocalizationOptions`